# Wso2Esb : using ConditionalRouter mediator based on URL

Tags: wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

I am having the same question but I am unable to know how to call the service for testing..

here are my Proxy.xml and sequences,

```
   <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="customproxycondroute"   transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <conditionalRouter continueAfter="false">
        <conditionalRoute breakRoute="false">
           <condition>
              <match type="url" regex="/test1/.*"/>
           </condition>
           <target sequence="calltest1"/>
        </conditionalRoute>
        <conditionalRoute breakRoute="false">
           <condition>
              <match type="url" regex="/test2/.*"/>
           </condition>
           <target sequence="calltest2"/>
        </conditionalRoute>
     </conditionalRouter>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
</target>
<description/>
```

```
 <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="calltest1">
    <send>
    <endpoint>
     <http method="get" uri-template="http://destinationserver:8080/rest/test1"></http>
  </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>

<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="calltest2">
  <send>
     <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="http://destinationserver:8080/rest/test1"></http>
       </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

I tried to access the proxy using curl

```
curl http://wso2esbserver:8080/test1/test
```

but it logs nothing and there were no errors... could anyone help me out in finding where I am going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your regex with `/services/customproxycondroute/test1/.*` and `/services/customproxycondroute/test2/.*`

and test with this url (if carbon offset is set to 0) : `http://wso2esbserver:8280/services/customproxycondroute/test1/test`

Comment: Yes, in your regex, you must consider the prefix /services/proxyname